# Стилизация некоторых элементов библиотеки Vuestic UI

Tags: ui, nuxt.js, vue3

Разрабатываю проект на nuxt3. На данный момент работаю с библиотекой Vuestic UI, которая изначально показалась мне очень прозрачной и понятной. Но, как оказалось, не во всём...

Вопрос 1.

Упёрся в чекбоксы. Переменные, указанные в документации, легко меняют форму и цвет бордера чекбоксов, атрибут `color` меняет цвет чекбокса, когда он выбран:

```
<va-checkbox
                v-model="item.checked"
                class="mb-6"
                :label="item.title"
                color="#ffffff"

        />
```

Но добиться изменения цвета галочки я так и не смог...
Использовал свойства

```
--va-checkbox-check-color: #B46B95;
--va-checkbox-checked-color: #B46B95;
```

но оно не работает... буду рад подсказке)

Вопрос 2.

Библиотека с какого то перепуга самостоятельно добавляет класс `.va-screen-md` к `body` со своими непонятными стилями, перекрывая мои. Этот класс относится к компоненту `Breakpoint`, который я не подключал. Я даже добавил в nuxt.config:

```
vuestic: {
        config: {

            breakpoint: {
                enable: false
            },

        }
    },
```

но это не помогло...
Временным решением оказалось прописать глобально

```
.va-screen-md {
    background: transparent;
}
```

но это не элегантно, и присутствие этого класса меня слегка раздражает...

Ну и вопрос 3.

Может, существует какая-нибудь прям удобная библиотека UI с поддержкой nuxt3?
Начинал я с element plus, но она вообще не прозрачная, свойства не прописаны в доках, с трудом можно кастомизировать стили. vuestic в этом смысле удобнее, но не идеален, но уже заметно удобнее) Может, есть что-то совсем комфортное?)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос 2. В nuxt.config.ts напиши следующее:

```
vuestic: {
    config: {

        breakpoint: {
            enabled: false,
            bodyClass: false,
        },

    }
```

и класс va-screen не будет добавляться

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/892347)